# Send value post method jquery at php page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hy i'am developing a phonegap application. I have this page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parsing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <script>

        $.getJSON(
                'http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, 
                function(data) {
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    var lin = data[i]["Nr SAT"];
                    $('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: <a href ="http://sat3.altervista.org/NuovoFile.html?id=' + lin + '">'+ data[i]["Nr SAT"] + '</a>'));        
                    $('body').append($('<p>').html('Data Apertura: '+ data[i]["Data Apertura"]));
                }
        });
        </script>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img id="logo" src="img/img2.png" alt="logo_chiave_inglese" />
        </header> 
    </body>
</html>
```

In which way i can send some value (for example : SAT000000002574) with the method post of jquery at this page http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php (that is the link of the page top).
And after that i have sent the number at the php page in wich way i can take this value??
I can not use php because phonegap doesn't support it, so i have to use jquery or javascript. Help me, please.

Comment: Why is your script tag in the middle of nowhere? It's not in the `<head>` or the `<body>`!

Comment: Don't worry it works. It isn't a problem. Can you solve my other problem?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I have to send a value at the php page that is in the html page at the top. And after this work in these page i have to thake the value .

Comment: send a value at .. in ... ?? Please explain what do you need ??? explain send FROM ... TO ...

Comment: I have an html page. I have to send the number SAT000000002574 from this html page to this php page: http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php    I can not use php but jquery or javacript....do you understand me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest example is this:

```
$.post('http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php', 
       {"param" : "SAT000000002574"},
       function(data) { ... } );
```

If your value is some data within the page, you can first grab it with jQuery as well.

```
var param = $("#myparam").val();
$.post('http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php', 
       {"param" : param},
       function(data) { ... } );
```

And the HTML...

```
<input type="text" name="myparam" id="myparam" value="SAT000000002574">
```